Flink Operator delete jar after upload in session mode
I'm testing flink operator 1.19 and confused by behaviour. I deployed session cluster with HA on s3 and try to add FlinkSessionJob with jar in Nexus, use this config:
spec:
  deploymentName: flink-cluster
  flinkConfiguration:
    kubernetes.operator.periodic.savepoint.interval: 10m
    state.savepoints.dir: s3://***
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3://***
    s3.access-key: ****
    s3.secret-key: ****
    s3.path-style-access: "true"
    s3.endpoint: https://minio.****
  job:
    entryClass: ***
    jarURI: https://***/test-1.0.0.jar
    parallelism: 3
    upgradeMode: stateless

but in operator logs i see this:
2024-09-20 10:29:04,031 o.a.f.k.o.l.AuditUtils         [INFO ][flink/flink-session-job] >>> Status | Info    | UPGRADING       | The resource is being upgraded 
2024-09-20 10:29:04,214 o.a.f.k.o.h.HealthProbe        [DEBUG] Checking event source health
2024-09-20 10:29:04,214 i.j.o.p.e.s.i.InformerWrapper  [DEBUG] Informer status: HEALTHY for for type: FlinkDeployment, namespace: JOSDK_ALL_NAMESPACES, details[ is running: true, has synced: true, is watching: true ]
2024-09-20 10:29:04,214 i.j.o.p.e.s.i.InformerWrapper  [DEBUG] Informer status: HEALTHY for for type: FlinkSessionJob, namespace: JOSDK_ALL_NAMESPACES, details[ is running: true, has synced: true, is watching: true ]
2024-09-20 10:29:04,214 i.j.o.p.e.s.i.InformerWrapper  [DEBUG] Informer status: HEALTHY for for type: Deployment, namespace: JOSDK_ALL_NAMESPACES, details[ is running: true, has synced: true, is watching: true ]
2024-09-20 10:29:04,214 i.j.o.p.e.s.i.InformerWrapper  [DEBUG] Informer status: HEALTHY for for type: FlinkDeployment, namespace: JOSDK_ALL_NAMESPACES, details[ is running: true, has synced: true, is watching: true ]
2024-09-20 10:29:04,214 i.j.o.p.e.s.i.InformerWrapper  [DEBUG] Informer status: HEALTHY for for type: FlinkSessionJob, namespace: JOSDK_ALL_NAMESPACES, details[ is running: true, has synced: true, is watching: true ]
2024-09-20 10:29:04,388 o.a.f.k.o.a.HttpArtifactFetcher [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Copied file from https://****/test-1.0.0.jar to /opt/flink/artifacts/flink/flink-cluster/flink-session-job/test-1.0.0.jar, cost 356 ms
2024-09-20 10:29:04,388 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Rest client endpoint started.
2024-09-20 10:29:04,389 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Sending request of class class org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.messages.EmptyRequestBody to flink-cluster-rest.flink:8081/v1/jars/upload
2024-09-20 10:29:04,765 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG] Received response {"filename":"/opt/flink/flink-web-upload/6c82bfd5-d65f-450c-b08b-d07f64cda8e4_test-1.0.0.jar","status":"success"}.
2024-09-20 10:29:04,765 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Shutting down rest endpoint.
2024-09-20 10:29:04,765 o.a.f.s.n.i.n.b.PoolThreadCache [DEBUG] Freed 18 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: flink-rest-client-netty-thread-1
2024-09-20 10:29:04,765 o.a.f.k.o.s.AbstractFlinkService [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Deleting the jar file /opt/flink/artifacts/flink/flink-cluster/flink-session-job/test-1.0.0.jar
2024-09-20 10:29:04,770 o.a.f.k.o.s.AbstractFlinkService [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Creating RestClusterClient(http://flink-cluster-rest.flink:8081)
2024-09-20 10:29:04,770 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Rest client endpoint started.
2024-09-20 10:29:04,770 o.a.f.k.o.s.AbstractFlinkService [INFO ][flink/flink-session-job] Submitting job: 17be29b566999b0eaeffd1394e17b681 to session cluster.
2024-09-20 10:29:04,770 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG] Sending request of class class org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunRequestBody to flink-cluster-rest.flink:8081/v1/jars/6c82bfd5-d65f-450c-b08b-d07f64cda8e4_test-1.0.0.jar/run
2024-09-20 10:29:04,775 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG] Received response {"errors":["Internal server error.","<Exception on server side:\njava.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Jar file /opt/flink/flink-web-upload/6c82bfd5-d65f-450c-b08b-d07f64cda8e4_test-1.0.0.jar does not exist\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.utils.JarHandlerUtils$JarHandlerContext.toPackagedProgram(JarHandlerUtils.java:180)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.utils.JarHandlerUtils$JarHandlerContext.applyToConfiguration(JarHandlerUtils.java:149)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.handleRequest(JarRunHandler.java:100)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandler.handleRequest(JarRunHandler.java:57)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.AbstractRestHandler.respondToRequest(AbstractRestHandler.java:83)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.AbstractHandler.respondAsLeader(AbstractHandler.java:196)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.LeaderRetrievalHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(LeaderRetrievalHandler.java:88)\n\tat java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.flink.util.OptionalConsumer.ifPresent(OptionalConsumer.java:45)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.LeaderRetrievalHandler.channelRead0(LeaderRetrievalHandler.java:85)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.LeaderRetrievalHandler.channelRead0(LeaderRetrievalHandler.java:50)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.router.RouterHandler.routed(RouterHandler.java:115)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.router.RouterHandler.channelRead0(RouterHandler.java:94)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.router.RouterHandler.channelRead0(RouterHandler.java:55)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler.channelRead0(FileUploadHandler.java:233)\n\tat org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler.channelRead0(FileUploadHandler.java:70)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\n\tat org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Jar file /opt/flink/flink-web-upload/6c82bfd5-d65f-450c-b08b-d07f64cda8e4_test-1.0.0.jar does not exist\n\t... 51 more\n\nEnd of exception on server side>"]}.
2024-09-20 10:29:04,776 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Shutting down rest endpoint.
2024-09-20 10:29:04,776 o.a.f.s.n.i.n.b.PoolThreadCache [DEBUG] Freed 5 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: flink-rest-client-netty-thread-1
2024-09-20 10:29:04,776 o.a.f.r.r.RestClient           [DEBUG][flink/flink-session-job] Rest endpoint shutdown complete.
2024-09-20 10:29:04,776 o.a.f.k.o.s.AbstractFlinkService [ERROR][flink/flink-session-job] Failed to submit job to session cluster.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Internal server error., <Exception on server side:
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Jar file /opt/flink/flink-web-upload/6c82bfd5-d65f-450c-b08b-d07f64cda8e4_test-1.0.0.jar does not exist
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.utils.JarHandlerUtils$JarHandlerContext.toPackagedProgram(JarHandlerUtils.java:180)

in jobmanager logs i see this:
2024-09-20 11:34:13,768 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Received request. URL:/v1/jars/upload Method:POST
2024-09-20 11:34:13,768 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Initializing multipart file upload.
2024-09-20 11:34:13,769 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Received http content.
2024-09-20 11:34:13,776 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Upload of attribute request complete.
2024-09-20 11:34:13,776 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Received http content.
2024-09-20 11:34:13,776 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Received http content.
...
...
...
2024-09-20 11:34:14,020 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Received http content.
2024-09-20 11:34:14,020 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Received http content.
2024-09-20 11:34:14,050 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Upload of file test-1.0.0.jar into destination /opt/flink/flink-web-upload/1d9efd38-d631-4340-ada0-0df5c65ee0ac/test-1.0.0.jar complete.
2024-09-20 11:34:14,050 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Received http content.
2024-09-20 11:34:14,050 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Finalizing multipart file upload.
2024-09-20 11:34:14,051 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarUploadHandler [] - Received request /v1/jars/upload.
2024-09-20 11:34:14,051 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarUploadHandler [] - Starting request processing.
2024-09-20 11:34:14,077 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler              [] - Received request. URL:/v1/jars/7f1c6d7d-dca8-44ec-83d7-2c3d87a3dc0b_test-1.0.0.jar Method:DELETE
2024-09-20 11:34:14,077 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarDeleteHandler [] - Received request /v1/jars/7f1c6d7d-dca8-44ec-83d7-2c3d87a3dc0b_test-1.0.0.jar.
2024-09-20 11:34:14,078 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarDeleteHandler [] - Starting request processing.

I don't understand why this step was created
"2024-09-20 11:34:14,077 TRACE org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.FileUploadHandler [] - Received request. URL:/v1/jars/7f1c6d7d-dca8-44ec-83d7-2c3d87a3dc0b_test-1.0.0.jar Method:DELETE"
